# Chrome UI with IE rendering engine?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Is there an application that wraps Microsoft's `WebBrower` control with a Chrome-style UI?

Or is there an extension for Chrome that uses IE's rendering engine?

i prefer Chrome's tabbed interface, but IE9's rendering is much faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) called IE Tab for chrome, it allows you to use the IE rendering engine inside the Chrome interface. More information on it [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd).

[image]

Comment: Actually, [there](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/miedgcmlgpmdagojnnbemlkgidepfjfi) [are](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fnfnbeppfinmnjnjhedifcfllpcfgeea) [quite](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gjgaiolkeejfnpjmjdgnngeibagbbkdo) [a](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cepflbjhkkhegamaeacdddihaphhgmci) [few](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dooekkcihpllpcfoioflgemikhfejpec).

Comment: I use IE Tab and it works great.  Highly recommended.

Comment: This one (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) doesn't use chrome's address bar. It looks like it forces IE to render through Chrome, making it extraordinarily slow (e.g. http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Performance/FishBowl/Default.html gets <1fps rather than 60fps)

Comment: You can try the other alternatives that Synetech inc. pointed out, try this one out, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/miedgcmlgpmdagojnnbemlkgidepfjfi